# How to upload a file in Laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-blade

Here is the code to upload an image to the database.

```php
public function create(Request $request)

{
    $this->validate($request, [

        'comment' => 'required',
    ]);

    $mess = new messageUser;
    $mess->user_id = Auth::guard('userLogin')->user()->id;
    $mess->message = $request->comment;

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $filenameWithExtention = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($filenameWithExtention,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameStore = $fileName .'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
        $path = $request->image->storeAs('images', $fileNameStore);
        $mess->attach = $fileNameStore;
    }

    $mess->save();
    return $mess;
}
```

**Blade**

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="compose-textarea" name="comment"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control inputFileVisible" placeholder="attach one file">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-fab btn-round btn-info"><i class="material-icons">attach an image</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>send image</button>
```

The code sends the message successfully but didn't upload the image.

Comment: Take a look at the docs https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-uploads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
  $filenameWithExtention = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
  $fileName = pathinfo($filenameWithExtention,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
  $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $fileNameStore = $fileName .'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
  $path = $request->photo->storeAs('images', $fileNameStore);
  $mess->attach = $fileNameStore;
}
```

For more Visit [this](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#files)

Thanks.

**Note:** Don't forget to run `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: nothing new. the return json as is ``` id 67
message "new message"
updated_at "2019-11-18 19:35:23"
created_at "2019-11-18 19:35:23"
id 112```

Comment: update your question with your entire code for that method

Comment: @bawad what do you want to return? it's returning the last created record..

Comment: but not returning image, nothing saved in db

Comment: what is the name of image field in your table?

Comment: the column for image is "attach"

Comment: try this `return $mess->attach;` what does this returns?

Comment: the return is save `id 67 message "new message" updated_at "2019-11-18 19:35:23" created_at "2019-11-18 19:35:23" id 112` same output

Comment: Your if condtion is not working...
Can you try without if condition and let me know.

Comment: @bawad are you adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form?

Comment: Happy to help. Cheers 

Answer (score 0):

What is the error show us please it will be better to guide you... BTW you ca use following code to uplaod an image/file

```
    if ($request->image) {
               $file = $request->File('image');
               $ext  = $student->username . "." . $file- 
   >clientExtension();
              $file->storeAs('images/', $ext);
              $student->image = $ext;
          }
```

Comment: the return value of request like this id 67 message "new message"
updated_at "2019-11-18 19:35:23"
created_at "2019-11-18 19:35:23"
id 112..... the image not found